# Gradle Installation Not Configured Correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, plugins, eclipse-neon

I installed Eclipse Neon and went to the marketplace and installed the Gradle IDE Pack 3.8.x + 1.0.x plugin. When I right click on the build.gradle file and choose run as > gradle build Gradle build I get an error that says "Gradle installation is not correctly configured go to Window -> Preferences -> Gradle(Enide) and configure the correct location.

I've tried multiple locations, including C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-3.1\bin, but none of them seem to be working.

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Also, I'm not sure if this is related but when I try "gradle build gradle" in the command prompt it says "Task 'gradle' not found in root project".

I've done some searching for both of these issue but don't seem to find then answer that seems right for my situation.  I've used gradle before but never set it up in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after trying to figure this out for the past 24 hours, I found out that when I ran "choco install gradle", it didn't install the most recent version of Gradle. I uninstalled that, downloaded and unzipped the current version (3.3) and pointed the GRADLE_HOME environment variable to the new directory and changed the Gradle directory in the PATH env variable, I was able to run it in Eclipse. gradle build gradle still isn't working for me but gradle build is. As far as I'm concerned, this is working as desired now.

The only reason I was trying to use gradle build gradle was because of past experiences but maybe that was something that was already setup in the project? I'm not really sure but this seems like it's working the way it is supposed ot now!